# Align one form and two text areas

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

I've got a FORM which contains a 32*50 TEXTAREA and a *Submit* button.

Now I'd like to align horizontally two text areas that contains additional information.  Ideally the three text areas (the one in which the user can type/paste and the two others) should have the same width and appear in three aligned columns.

If I wanted to do that, should I use only HTML?  If so, how?  A table with one row and three td?  (Sample code would be most welcome).

Or would you rather suggest CSS?

Comment: Could you paste the code you have at the moment, or perhaps a jsfiddle?

Comment: Is this the one you need? http://jsfiddle.net/FATfJ/

Comment: @itea, why not post your comment as an answer, but with the code directly i the answer as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

textarea is inline element and they would be horizontally aligned if the container is larger enough in width. So, see http://jsfiddle.net/FATfJ/ I don't know if this is the exact one you need.

code:

```
<form id="a-form">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
</form>

#a-form textarea {width: 100px;}
```

Comment: woaw.  +1 to all... jsfiddle seems to rock a lot!  Yes, this seems to be what I'm after.  It's excellent to be able to see the result directly in jsfiddle!

Answer (score 2):

Since `textarea` is an inline element, you can just put such elements after another. They will then appear in one line if they fit it but wrap to two or three lines if needed.

If you would rather force horizontal scrolling when there is not enough horizontal space, you can use a one-row table. There would be nothing special with the markup:

```
<table><tr><td><textarea ...></textarea>
           <td><textarea ...></textarea>
           <td><textarea ...></textarea>
</table>
```

But if you wish to fine-tune the rendering, then that’s best done with CSS.

If the `textarea` elements need labels, as they usually do, you can place them in another row of the table (at its start).

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you need a nice combination on CSS and HTML. You could perhaps use fieldsets to put your fields in and then float them next to each other using CSS. You can set widths and margins etc using CSS and you should be able to line everything up this way.

You could use tables to do this but I find that they can add more code than is really required.